# Hows best to unsubscribe from an observable using a takeUntil in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hows best to unsubscribe from an observable using a takeUntil.

From what I understand takeUntil automatically does the complete for you.

Below is how I normally do a unsubscribe from an observable.
But not sure if done correctly. Do I really need the "this.destroyed$.complete();" if takeUntil does the complete for me?

**This is my current attempt that works but unsure if best method:**

```
 private destroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

 ngOnIt(): void {
    this.serviceA.getData
      .takeUntil(this.$destroyed)
      .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('Current value:', val);
      });
  };

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  };
```

I was thinking of removing the .complete in the ngOnDestory but not sure if that would cause memory leaks?

Comment: have you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription ?*

Comment: That link has lots of examples and I just want an answer really for if I'm doing it right? Thanks for that link though

Comment: Just read the validation answer: --- Edit 3 - The 'Official' Solution (2017/04/09). This is the best way, validated by team member from Angular

Comment: Wandrille, I've read the bit your referring too and it seems my solution above is correct. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, this is the good way.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer this solution, have another subject just to handle unsubscribe and mix up with takeUntil probably make things too complex

```
 private _subscriptions:Subscription[];

 ngOnIt(): void {
  this._subscriptions.push(this.serviceA.getData
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log('Current value:', val);
  })
   )
};

ngOnDestroy(): void {
this._subscriptions.foreach(subs=>{ subs.unsubscribe()})
};
```

Comment: I prefer my solution. But @Fan it would be good to know if yours definitely works because it's missing a complete()

Comment: The objective is to unsubscribe everything upon NgDestroy, the oncomplete is the complete the side effect destroy subject in your approach so it's not quite related.